# Symfony2 Ajax app_dev.php in url

Tags: ajax, symfony

Just starting out in Symfony2 and really loving it after being a long time ZF1 developer.

Started to add some Ajax functionality to a site tonight and am a bit confused about the following.

in my ajax call eg:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/app_dev.php/ajax/urlgetter',
    data: "url="+urlinput,
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
         // DO Stuff here
    }
});
```

I had to add /app_dev.php to the url to make it work in dev environment. Is there not a better way of doing this? Does this mean when I change the project to a production environment I need to search and replace all instances of /app_dev.php?? Hopefully I have totally missed something simple.

Comment: You should setup your dev computer in a way you don't have to happen `app_dev.php` to reach your dev environnement but instead use a virtual host (or equivalent).

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using the jsrouting-bundle

Once installed I could simply do the following:

```
$.ajax({
     url: Routing.generate('urlgetter'),
    data: "url="+urlinput,
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
     // DO Stuff here
    }
});
```

where urlgetter is a route defined in routing.yml like:

```
urlgetter:
    pattern: /ajax/urlgetter
    defaults: { _controller: MyAjaxBundle:SomeController:urlgetter }
    options:
        expose: true
```

notice the expose: true option has to be set for the route to work with jsrouting-bundle

Answer (score 3):

I guess this question is already kind of old but I came across the same problem.

Its not any "best practice" solution but here is what I do.

In `twig` you can use this `{{ path('yourRouteName') }}` thing in a perfect way. So in my `twig` file I have a structure like that:

```
...    
<a href="{{ path('myRoute') }}"> //results in e.g http://localhost/app_dev.php/myRoute
    <div id="clickMe">Click</div>
</a>
```

Now if someone clicks the div, I do the following in my `.js file`:

```
$('#clickMe').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevents the default a href behaviour
    var url = $(this).closest('a').attr('href');
    $.ajax({
       url: url,
       method: 'POST',
       success: function(data) {
           console.log('GENIUS!');
      }  
    });
});
```

I know that this is not a solution for every situation where you want to trigger an Ajax request but I just leave this here and perhaps somebody thinks it's useful :)

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448563/how-to-render-twig-path-call-as-jquery-ajax-url This also seems like a nice alternative

Answer (score 1):

Since this jQuery ajax function is placed on twig side and the url points to your application you can insert routing path

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ path("your_ajax_routing") }}',
    data: "url="+urlinput,
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
         // DO Stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: This did not work. The path would be passed exactly as {{ path("urlgetter") }}. Is there something that needs to be configured for this to work out of the box? I ended up using FOSJsRoutingBundle instead.