# how to render twig {{path('')}} call as jquery ajax url

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I am using ajax request from a modal box to save data in my symfony2 application. The modal markup is render when the modal box is called. So I cannot really use the "" signs anywhere in my modal box markup.

My code is:

```
var path = {{ path('_inserttask') }};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: path,
        data: { myid: 123456 },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
                $('#mask').remove();
            });
        }
    });
```

It gives an error in the console when the ajax is called. I identified that if I use hard coded url - it works! But using `{{ path('_inserttask') }}` as url gives error. I understand it is for the quote signs that I am not using. How to solve the problem? it already killed 2 hours :-(

Comment: have you tried this?

var path = '{{ path('_inserttask') }}';

Comment: @KernelFolla, yes it gives syntax error. May be some sort of solution with htmlentities or something which don't count the quotation may work around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From what I see above you haven't put double quotes on the value of the path variable. Try this -

```
var path = "{{ path('_inserttask') }}";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: path,
    data: { myid: 123456 },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
            $('#mask').remove();
        });
    }
});
```

And one think more, You are embedding this script in the twig template that will later render to html and then send to the browser right? If yes the I think the above change will fix the issue.

If you are trying to use twig in a pure javascript file. I don't think it will work. If you are doing this way. I think you try to put the path value in the html and then use javascript to get that value and then call the ajax instead. for example. I would choose to  embedded that path url in one of attribute of a div.

In my twig template file (for example index.html.twig)

```
<div id="abc" data-path="{{path('_inserttask')}}">
</div>
```

In my javascript file (for example abc.js)

```
var path = $("#abc").attr("data-path");
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: path,
    data: { myid: 123456 },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
            $('#mask').remove();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow! with single quote `<div id="abc" data-path="{{path('_inserttask')}}">
</div>` this worked like charm. for your first solution i have mentioned that I cannot add "" here cause it will cause syntax error. However thanks a lot for the solution. I have no voting power  right now else I would upvote you!

Comment: No problems @HimelNagRana. I faced this issue before. but I am not so sure, this is right way of doing it or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I was struggling with this for hours!

Comment: Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117779/rails-edit-action-not-updating-and-not-work-properly-using-ajax