# Rails Edit action not updating and not work properly using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-6

**I am trying to do two things**:

1. With Ajax render Edit form when a user clicks on Edit link/button
2. Then after editing and they click on Update link/button, hide the form.

...but unfortunately, it didn't behave that way. It perfectly renders the form through Ajax but...

> 1. it renders the form on all of the rows.
> 2. after edit and you click update it doesn't hide the form.

Below is the code:

**controller**

```
before_action :set_clock_entry, only: [:edit, :update]


def edit
end

def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @clock_entry.update(clock_entry_params)
        format.js { flash.now[:notice] = 'Clock entry was successfully updated.' }
        format.html { redirect_to @clock_entry, notice: 'Clock entry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @clock_entry }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @clock_entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Editing Clock Entry</h1>

<%= render 'form', clock_entry: @clock_entry %>

<%= link_to 'Back', clock_entries_path %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for clock_entry, remote: true do |f| %> # I am setting remote: true here
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :purpose %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**edit.js.erb**

```
$('#edit-clock-entry a').hide().parent().append("<%= j render 'form', clock_entry: @clock_entry %>")
```

**html edit link**

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div id="edit-clock-entry">
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_clock_entry_path(clock_entry), remote: true %>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**This is the image - it renders on all ids**

[image]

Comment: edit-clock-entry shouldn't be an id as it won't be unique to each row.  You should make it so the id is unique to each row such as:   <div id="edit-clock-entry-#{clock_entry.id}">  That will at least ensure only the row clicked upon will open and close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give it all/dedicate it to @bkunzi01's comment under the post to the problem/question and that is what helped me solved it. So this is how I eventually solved it:

**Error 1**:

So according to what was suggested as I mentioned earlier, I had to redefine my `edit.js.erb` file to handle unique id of the edit in the row. So my **edit.js.erb** becomes:

```
$('#edit-clock-entry-<%= @clock_entry.id %> a').hide().parent().append("<%= j render 'form', clock_entry: @clock_entry %>")
```

**Error 2**:

I did not create update action with ajax and that made it behaved the way it behaved. So I created a file called `update.js.erb` to handle what happens when users hit the update button. So my **update.js.erb** becomes:

```
$('.refresh').bind('ajax:success', function () {
    $(this).hide().parent();
})
```

**So this is what I have now shown in the image**

[image]

**Log also shows the right record was updated**

[image: log image]

This fixed it for me.